# Coffeescript: Add a conditional classname governed by a boolean

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, react-rails

I am trying to add a class name to an element in react using this:

```
className: "btn btn-primary #{!@valid() ? 'disabled' : ''}"
```

However this is leading to `class="btn btn-primary true"`

This coffee code is compiled to the incorrect JS as follows:

```
className: "btn btn-primary " + ((ref = !this.valid()) != null ? ref : {
          'disabled': ''
        }),
```

What is the correct syntax of doing this in coffee?

Comment: CoffeeScript doesn't have a `? :` ternary, it uses `if x then y else z`. I don't know the context well enough but you might have problems with what `@` is when building that string too.

Comment: Yes, that totally works. Can you post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript doesn't have a C-style `?:` ternary so this:

```
!@valid() ? 'disabled' : ''
```

is parsed as:

```
!@valid() ? ({ 'disabled' : '' })
```

which is an [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators):

> **The Existential Operator**
>
> It's a little difficult to check for the existence of a variable in JavaScript. `if (variable)` ... comes close, but fails for zero, the empty string, and false. CoffeeScript's existential operator `?` returns true unless a variable is **null** or **undefined**, which makes it analogous to Ruby's `nil?`

combined with an object literal. Hence the odd looking JavaScript you're seeing.

CoffeeScript uses [`if` expressions](http://coffeescript.org/#conditionals) instead of `?:`:

> CoffeeScript can compile **if** statements into JavaScript expressions, using the ternary operator when possible, and closure wrapping otherwise. There is no explicit ternary statement in CoffeeScript — you simply use a regular **if** statement on a single line.

If you'd say this in JavaScript:

```
!this.valid() ? 'disabled' : ''
```

then you'd say this in CoffeeScript:

```
if !@valid() then 'disabled' else ''
```

and since `"#{...}"` works with an expression:

```
className: "btn btn-primary #{if @valid() then 'disabled' else ''}"
```